# Camera calibration in opencv output distorted images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm trying to use calibrateCamera in opencv2 to calibrate webcams from YouTube (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpwfjhmyEzw). Anyway, I tried to use a script from here: `https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html`,  (and many other similar scripts) and the result I get are very distorted, and not similar at all to the results they present.
This is my code (which is just a copy-paste from their):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import os

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.
images = ['C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive - SAIPS\\Pictures\\left12.png']
for fname in images:
    img = cv.imread(fname)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6), None)
    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray,corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners)
        # Draw and display the corners
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners2, ret)
        cv.imshow('img', img)
        cv.waitKey(500)
cv.destroyAllWindows()

ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

img = cv.imread(images[0])
h,  w = img.shape[:2]
newcameramtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (w,h), 1, (w,h))

# undistort
dst = cv.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
# crop the image
x, y, w, h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv.imwrite('method1.png', dst)


# undistort
mapx, mapy = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx, (w,h), 5)
dst = cv.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_LINEAR)
# crop the image
x, y, w, h = roi
dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv.imwrite('method2.png', dst)
```

these are the outputs:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like the undistortion is overfitting to the center region of the image. Try to present more images with variation of chessboard positions and rotations during calib.

Comment: conversely, not fitting the far corners, because there are _no_ sample points there to pin the model down. -- how would you even come up with calibration data for random *fixed* cameras you can't wave a calibration pattern in front of and that don't move (so no auto-calibration either)? -- you'd have more luck with simply tweaking the distortion coefficients manually, starting from all zero, until the picture "looks good". you could pick points on a line in your camera feed, but OpenCV calibration math assumes pinned down points, not points that can slide along a line